# How to automate test cases by giving multiple inputs?

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver/wait'

username = 'abcd'
password = '1234'

Watir::Browser.new :firefox

puts 'Beginning of test: Yahoo Login.'
puts ' Step 1: go to the test site: ' + '<https://mail.yahoo.com>'
browser = Watir::Browser.start '<https://mail.yahoo.com>'

puts 'Step 2: enter username'
browser.text_field(id: 'login-username').when_present.set(username)
browser.text_field(id: 'login-username').wait_until_present

puts 'Step 3: enter password'
browser.text_field(:id, 'login-passwd').set(password)

puts 'Step 4: Check keep me signed in check box'
browser.checkbox(:id, 'persistent').clear

puts 'Step 5: Click sign in button'
browser.button(:value, 'Sign In').click

if browser.text.include? ' This ID is not yet taken. '
  puts 'Testcase01 pass : Enter a valid username '
  Kernel.exit(false)
end

if browser.text.include? 'Please enter your password'
  puts 'Testcase02 pass : password can not be blank'
  Kernel.exit(false)
end

browser.button(id: 'mail-search-btn').when_present
browser.button(id: 'mail-search-btn').wait_until_present

if browser.text.include? 'Hemanth'
  puts 'Testcase04 pass : ***Login successfull'
else
  puts '***Error in Login'
end
```

Now it gets the job done for single user name and password, and I need to loop it to check for 4 test cases?  I mean I need to pass 4 combinations of username and passwords for the above script.  How can I do that?

here is the test cases
testcase               username        password      signin
tc_yahoo_login_01    abcd                  xyz123      true
tc_yahoo_login_02    abcde             abcd123      false
tc_yahoo_login_03                   abc123      true
tc_yahoo_login_04    abcd                          true
tc_yahoo_login_05    abcd                     abcd123     false
these are the test cases i need to implement and only once successful login will happen. do you got any idea what output im trying to get?

Comment: You could create an array of hashes (where the key/value pairs are username/password combinations) and iterate over it.  You'd probably need to add logout and go to login page steps at the end of the script as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @orde but i need to know how to use them if you can add a piece of code that will give me an idea how to use them i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: your code above makes a lot of assumptions regarding the causes of the messages you expect to see.   for example if your password was not blank, but you got the password cannot be blank message 

I suggest you look into a framework for doing tests, and put your watir code inside of that.. something like Cucumber, Rspec, or another functional or unit testing tool ought to suffice.. then you can also make each test more atomic and stand alone, instead of a big long chain script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below creates a [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) called users (which contains usernames/passwords), launches a browser, iterates over the hash, and prints the key and value for each key/value pair:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
users = {"user_one" => "password", "user_two" => "password"}

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto('http://www.example.org')
users.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value
  b.refresh
end

#=> user_one
#=> password
#=> user_two
#=> password
```

To use symbols as hash keys, you'd do the same but convert the key to a string:

```
users = {user_one: "password", user_two: "password"}

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto('http://www.example.org')
users.each do |key, value|
  puts key.to_s                    # convert symbol to string
  puts value
  b.refresh
end
```

And a working demo:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
users = {sample: "sample", sample1: "sample1", sample2: "sample2"} # hash of users
b = Watir::Browser.new                                             # launch browser
b.goto('https://foodclub.org/sample/login')
users.each do |key, value|                                         # iterate on hash
  b.text_field(name: "user_id").set  key.to_s                      # set key as username
  b.text_field(name: "password").set value                         # set value as password
  b.button(name: "login").click
  b.link(text: "Logout").click
end
```